# What is difference between SharePoint Framework (SPFx) Extensions and SharePoint Framework (SPFx) Web PART

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-extensions

I have started working on SharePoint Online.
Where I have to use SPFX.

What is the Difference between SharePoint Framework (SPFx) Web Part and SharePoint Framework (SPFx) Extensions

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Web parts allow you to create components that can be added by content editors as content on a page. Extensions add functionality to known areas of pages on an entire site or site collection,  for example to add things in the header or footer of every page, or add menu options in a list toolbar. Extensions are often added by administrators.

Both use the SharePoint Framework (spfx).

Does it help?

Comment: What if I want to create a whole new design,  like for example a full with Single Page Application or an react admin dashboard-like design. Should I create it as webpart or an extension?

Comment: @aventus,in this case , I would suggest that you build a single page application web part.. these instructions will point you in the right direction: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/single-part-app-pages